# MEAN Stack user authentication with passport-auth0 , calling NodeJs passport-auth0 API in Anguler

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, mean-stack

I have used passport-auth0 in my MEAN demo project. If I have to call this api in a url in the browser it will work properly, but if I hit this url in Angular (api) its throwing CORS error.

My main goal is to create a multiple authentication provider application, authentication strategy will change the user email address

[image]

Comment: You are unable to call your API from localhost. [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the cors to your `Node.js` app file. You can do this:

```
npm install cors
```

In your file:

```
const express = require('express'), 
      cors = require('cors'),
      app = express();

app.use(cors())
```

Check [here](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for more details.

Comment: CORS is already installed

Comment: It seems an Third party API call is failing due to CORS. You might need to add localhost to its config to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Use CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

// Other middleware and route configurations
// ...

// Start your Express server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```